# Need help with cube roots of unity

Tags: complex-numbers

The question is:

If z = $(1+i$$\sqrt3$)$^{100}$
find Re(z)/Im(z)

What I've tried so far is attached below:
[image]

Now, I am unable to match my answer with the options. The option contains a positive value of what seems to be coming out to be negative for me.
Can anyone of you point out my mistake and thus help me with a small hint?

Comment: Converting $1 + i\sqrt{3}$ to polar form would make this simpler.

Comment: Since I can only do one (I can't read your handwriting), I will put this in a comment: Try converting to polar form (and then back if you need to). Polar form is useful, especially in exponentiating complex numbers.

Comment: Nice hint man! I will surely do it and let you know in a moment.

Comment: Not working! Answer is still turning out to be in negative. Dang!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$z_1=1+i\sqrt3=2e^{i\pi/3}\Rightarrow z=z_1^{100}=2^{100}e^{i100\pi/3}=2^{100}e^{i(32\pi+4\pi/3)}=2^{100}e^{i4\pi/3}$$
Therefore,
$$\frac{Re(z)}{Im(z)}=\frac{\cos(4\pi/3)}{\sin(4\pi/3)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}3$$

Comment: I am sorry for the inconvenience, but, I have updated my query. The question asks for Re(z)/Im(z).

Comment: @Abhishekstudent I just updated the answer considering your new question.

Comment: Great method, sir! Keep up the good work! @msm

Comment: Glad that I could help! @Abhishekstudent